# Is is possible to extract a Predicate's conditions?

Tags: java, lambda, java-8, predicate

Is it possible somehow to extract Predicate conditions in Java 8 inside method?
For example:

```
package test;

import java.util.function.Predicate;

public class Test {

    public static main(String[] args) {
        new Test().filter(p -> p.foo() == 5);
    }

    public void filter(Predicate<Clazz> p) {
        System.out.println(p.toString());
    }
}
```

And to get output something like:

```
p.foo() == 5
```

Comment: By reading and decompiler the compiled code, it is. Look for ASM and look for Java decompiler. After all, it's a quite complex task.

Comment: I just try to retrieve conditions to transform them to SQL WHERE, for example

Comment: Than the problem becomes even more complex. The first two steps remain and finally, you need to translate the statement to sql.

Comment: So you need to print the body of the `accept` function! In java not a simlpee task if possible at all.